# Mysql not generating log when connection fails

Tags: mysql, connection

I am continuously getting  below error while connecting to mysql-

```
Can\'t connect to MySQL server on /ip/address
```

but mysql is not generating any log for this error. I have below entries in my.cnf file

```
log=/var/log/mysql_err.log
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
```

I am using correct credentials. No issue of conections. 
Now how will I determine the exact issue If I'll not get any log ?
Any Idea, how to solve this ?

Comment: How can a server generate a log event for something that didn't happen to it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not surprising:

the server can only log an incident it is aware of. However your client does not even reach the server at all! So how should the server know some client has attempted to contact it?

The error message you get clearly indicates that you *do* have a connection issue. 
You can easily make a test to check the most common problems: just open a telnet connection from the system trying to connect to the system the sql server runs on, connect to the mysql port: `telnet <ip-of-mysql-server> mysql`

On typical unixoid systems "mysql" will be substituted by the "well known port number of mysql, which is 3306. otherwise you have to specify it manually. Do you get a connection at all? I would guess not. This means either the mysql server is not listening where expected (not running or configured otherwise) or the connection is blocked on network level (firewall).

Comment: I tested it already that's why I have written "No issue of connections". No any connection issue between server but still I am getting can't connect to mysql error.

Comment: Sorry, that is a contradiction. So I want to ask: _what_ have you tested? Did you _really_ test this connection? Did you use the `telnet` command as explained above? Or did you just do a ping or something?

Comment: I tested telnet, mtr & ping. Everytime I successfully connected but at the same time I was getting mysql error. Then I tested tcp connections. Around 10k connections were in TIME_WAIT and 1 ESTABLISHED. Suggest me anything else which is remaining to test.

Comment: Could you post the output of the telnet test please?

Comment: telnet ip/address 3306
Trying ip/address...
Connected to ip/address.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.5.32-log X2^cXm='�v=iyF0ZW(^"*mysql_native_password

Comment: Ok, thanks, that looks good. Interesting. Then there must be some other reason, most likely the client connecting somewhere else. What type of client is this? What is its configuration?